# Client Automatically disconnects after some time in websocket

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, websocket

My desktop App client is connecting to web server through `webSockets`. I am using `javaWebSocket` api for the client side, and I am using Apache tomcat 7's `webSocketServlet`. I do't know what I am doing wrong but client is connecting perfectly with webserver and sending chat messages but after spending some time idle, the server automatically disconnects the client. I want the client to be connected until the client intentionally don't want to disconnect. Here are my sample codes of web `Socket` servlet and client. First is the client code

```
Draft[] drafts = { new Draft_10(), new Draft_17(), new Draft_76(), new Draft_75() };
cc = new WebSocketClient( new URI( uriField.getText() ), (Draft) draft.getSelectedItem() ) {

                @Override
                public void onMessage( String message ) {
                    ta.append( "got: " + message + "\n" );
                    ta.setCaretPosition( ta.getDocument().getLength() );
                }

                @Override
                public void onOpen( ServerHandshake handshake ) {
                    ta.append( "You are connected to ChatServer: " + getURI() + "\n" );
                    ta.setCaretPosition( ta.getDocument().getLength() );
                }

                @Override
                public void onClose( int code, String reason, boolean wasClean ) {
                    ta.append( "You have been disconnected from: " + getURI() + "; Code: " + code + " " + reason + "\n" );
                    System.out.println("the reason for disconnection is ........ "+wasClean);
                                            ta.setCaretPosition( ta.getDocument().getLength() );
                    connect.setEnabled( true );
                    uriField.setEditable( true );
                    draft.setEditable( true );
                    close.setEnabled( false );
                }

                @Override
                public void onError( Exception ex ) {
                    ta.append( "Exception occured ...\n" + ex + "\n" );
                    ta.setCaretPosition( ta.getDocument().getLength() );
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    connect.setEnabled( true );
                    uriField.setEditable( true );
                    draft.setEditable( true );
                    close.setEnabled( false );
                }
            };

            close.setEnabled( true );
            connect.setEnabled( false );
            uriField.setEditable( false );
            draft.setEditable( false );
            cc.connect();
        } catch ( URISyntaxException ex ) {
            ta.append( uriField.getText() + " is not a valid WebSocket URI\n" );
        }
    } else if( e.getSource() == close ) {
        cc.close();
    }
```

and now this is the servlet code.

```
private static ArrayList<MyStreamBound> mmiList = new ArrayList<MyStreamBound>();

@Override
protected StreamInbound createWebSocketInbound(String protocol) {
    return new MyStreamBound();
}



private class MyStreamBound extends StreamInbound{
    WsOutbound myoutbound;

     @Override
     public void onOpen(WsOutbound outbound){
         try {
             System.out.println("Open Client.");
             this.myoutbound = outbound;
             mmiList.add(this);
             outbound.writeTextMessage(CharBuffer.wrap("Hello!"));

         } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }


    @Override
    protected void onBinaryData(InputStream arg0) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onTextData(Reader recievedData) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(recievedData);
        String line = null;
        StringBuilder rslt = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            rslt.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println(rslt.toString()); 

        for(MyStreamBound mmib: mmiList){
             CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.wrap(rslt.toString());
             mmib.myoutbound.writeTextMessage(buffer);
             mmib.myoutbound.flush();

         }

    }

     @Override
     protected void onClose(int status){
         System.out.println("Close Client."+status);
         mmiList.remove(this);
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i managed to solve it. Problem was with tomcat's configuration file. You have to go to the following directory ApacheTomcat->Config->server.xml, There is attribute with the name of connection time out default value is 20000Ms(20 Seconds) change it to -1 for infinite connection time.

Comment: what is the ideal value for timeout that you used ?

Answer (score 3):

You may have to implement a keep-alive mechanism.

In general proxies destroy websocket connections after some time.

You may have a look in this : [Atmosphere timeout issue with tomcat 7.0.39](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309971/atmosphere-timeout-issue-with-tomcat-7-0-39)

Comment: Proxies from client side/server side or both? if proxies destroys them then how to manage this ? keep alive meaning have to periodically send a ping message to server ???